# Exception not handled in JSONObjectWithData iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, exception

I am getting a random crash while parsing `NSData` into dictionary. I used the following code.

```
 -(NSArray *)enumDataParser:(NSMutableData *)responseData
    {   
        @try { 
            NSError *error;      
            NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            [[IFieldServiceCrashLog sharedLog] writeExceptionLogFile:exception];
            [self performCatchOperation:exception];
        }
    }
```

Sometimes I am getting "nil", and other times my app crashes (`Exception not catched`).

I am sure `responseData` is not nil, since whenever the crash happens, `"error"` does not give me a reason (error found as nil).

App crashes at method `JSONObjectWithData` itself. How can I fix this or handle in exception?

Comment: It seems it is unrelated to "Swift", is there a need to add its tag?

Comment: You can't catch all errors, and you can't catch the error if `responseData` is nil if I remember correctly. There might be other error that you can't catch. Just check if `responseData` is nil.

Comment: No point enclosing this in `@try @catch` since in Objective-C this method does not throw an exception, or at least not due to serialization error.

Comment: @Larme. responseData is not nil. as i send message JSONObjectWithData to response data it gets crashed. any workaround ?

Comment: How do you get `responseData`? Does your response return `NSData`, or does it return `NSString`, that you turn to `NSData` using `dataUsingEncoding`?

Comment: Is `responseData` really a `NSData` object (and not nil)? I'm wondering if it will cause a crash uncatchable then too.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Deserialization only Dictionary or Array, so you can check and see the log.
Other, see options type:  ->  Enumeration NSJSONReadingOptions like "options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments"

```
typedef enum NSJSONReadingOptions : NSUInteger {
    NSJSONReadingMutableContainers = (1UL << 0),
    NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves = (1UL << 1),
    NSJSONReadingAllowFragments = (1UL << 2)
} NSJSONReadingOptions;
```

Example:

```
NSError *error = nil;

id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"***** %@", error.localizedDescription);
} else if (jsonObject != nil) {
    NSLog(@"*** JSON Data converted to NSObject!");
    if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSDictionary *deserializedDictionary = (NSDictionary *)jsonObject;
        NSLog(@"JSON Obj class: %@", NSStringFromClass([deserializedDictionary class]));
        NSLog(@"*** its Dictionary Object from JSON Data: %@", deserializedDictionary.description);
    } else if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSArray *deserializedArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;
        NSLog(@"JSON Obj class: %@", NSStringFromClass([deserializedArray class]));
        NSLog(@"*** its Array Object from JSON Data: %@", deserializedArray.description);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"JSON Obj class: %@", NSStringFromClass([jsonObject class]));
        NSLog(@"*** its UNKNOWN Object from JSON Data: %@", jsonObject);
    }
}
```